# Array element are undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The array elements in Bind are undefined even though there is data in bindInfo.
Any suggestions.

```
let bindinfo =
{
    clientid: 1,
    clientname: 'Web Client',
    nowutc: now_utc,
    bindlist: Bindings(this.props.bindDetails)

}
Bindings(bin)
{
    var Bind = [];
    Bind = bin.map(bindItem => {
        var bindInfo;
        bindInfo = {
            bindingid: bindItem.bindId,
            function: bindItem.functionName,
            aggregation: bindItem.aggregation,
            datalimit: bindItem.datalimit
        }
        Bind.push(bindInfo);
    });
    return Bind;
}
```

Comment: Q: What is an example value for `this.props.bindDetails`?  Q: Can you set a breakpoint in the debugger to look at each bindItem?  Q: What does the debugger say about value of Bind just before you return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `.map` operation completes, `bind` is assigned to the result of the `.map` - that is, the element returned on each iteration of `.map` is the new array elemenet. But you never return anything from the mapper function, so even if you initially `push` to `Bind`, your later *reassignment* of `Bind` resets it.

Either use `.map` properly and return the item on each iteration:

```
const Bind = bin.map(bindItem => {
  return {
    bindingid: bindItem.bindId,
    function: bindItem.functionName,
    aggregation: bindItem.aggregation,
    datalimit: bindItem.datalimit
  };
});
```

Or (not recommended) use `forEach` rather than `.map`, and don't reassign `Bind`:

```
const Bind = [];
bin.forEach(bindItem => {
  var bindInfo = {
    bindingid: bindItem.bindId,
    function: bindItem.functionName,
    aggregation: bindItem.aggregation,
    datalimit: bindItem.datalimit
  }
  Bind.push(bindInfo);
});
```

Use `.map` when you want to transform one array into another *through the result of the call of `.map`*. Otherwise, for generic looping, use `forEach`.